# Is there any way to convert spectrogram into MFCCs directly?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, librosa

Is there any way to convert spectrogram into MFCCs directly? If yes, kindly provide python script for that. Thanks

Comment: Is the input an STFT spectrogram, or a mel-filtered spectrogram, or a log-scaled mel-filtered spectrogram? The steps needed are different depending on that

Comment: I have a power spectrogram converted to decibel units.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally got the answer!
I have converted power spectrum in db units back to its original scale using https://librosa.org/doc/0.8.1/generated/librosa.db_to_power.html#librosa.db_to_power

Then, I passed power spectrum directly into librosa.feature.mfcc to get mfccs.